# Alexandrescus smart assert with return value

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using Andrei Alexandrescus smart assert technique for my assert facility, basically the interface is:

```
ASSERT( foo == bar, "Foo doesn't equal bar!" )( foo )( bar );
```

As it turns out, often when the assert doesn't hold one wants to do an early exit, which leads me to the following overload:

```
ASSERT( foo == bar, "Foo doesn't equal bar!", 0 )( foo )( bar )
```

Sadly one limitation of the recursive macro trick which this is based upon is that the macro must end with another macro which kicks everything into gears, which leads me to the following piece of code for supporting a return value:

```
#define ASSERT3( expr, msg, ret ) \  
    if( (expr) ); \  
    else \  
    return ret + MakeAssert().AddContext( #expr, msg, BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION, __FILE__, __LINE__ ).SMART_ASSERT_A
```

By overloading `operator+()` for the `Assert` class this works out nicely, but here's the kicker and problem I'm currently facing: This method can't be used for either functions which returns `void`, constructors or destructors.

Comment: /offtopic: Why do I keep reading 'smart ass'?

Comment: So what's the question?  How to handle constructors, destructors, and functions returning `void`?  Whether there's a different smart assert?  How to make really weird recursive macros?

Comment: The question is if anyone knows how one could get this to work with void & for constructors & destructors. Return void(); is valid for functions returning void, but that seems to be pretty much where it ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not quite satisfactorily, I post this just in case this can be a hint
for you:

```
#define ASSERT3( expr, msg, ret, ... )                                  \
    if( (expr) );                                                       \
    else {                                                              \
        MakeAssert().AddContext(....).SMART_ASSERT_A __VA_ARGS__;       \
        return ret;                                                     \
    }

ASSERT3( foo == bar, "...", 0, ( foo )( bar ) ) // usage
```